# Run-time check failure #0 + COM

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, opengl, com

Добрый день. Помогите пожалуйста, уже который день не могу разобраться с ошибкой. Есть WinAPI обертка. Этот оконный класс наследуется COM классом GraphEngine.

```
class GraphEngine : public IEngine, public ULWnds::CULWnd
{
public:
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(const IID& iid, void** ppv) ;
    virtual ULONG __stdcall AddRef() ;
    virtual ULONG __stdcall Release() ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall Draw();
private:
    //Обработка нажатия кнопок мыши
    LRESULT  LeftMouseDown(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
         MessageBox(NULL,"","",MB_OK);
         Draw();
         return true;
    }     
} ;
```

Кидаю LeftMouseDown в карту сообщений, которая имеется в родительском классе CULWnd, на сообщение WM_LBUTTONDOWN. Когда же запускаю все это дело, при нажатии левой кнопки мыши выдает ошибку:

> Run-Time Check Failure #0 — The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call. This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention

Пробовал менять функцию так:

```
LRESULT  LeftMouseDown(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MessageBox(NULL,"","",MB_OK);
    GraphEngine::Draw();
    return true;
}
```

Ошибку не выдает. Отрабатывает даже месседжбокс. Но OpenGL функции, которые находятся в Draw не отрабатывают. Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

Comment: >"Кидаю LeftMouseDown в карту сообщений, которая имеется в родительском классе CULWnd, на сообщение WM_LBUTTONDOWN"

покажите как вы это делаете.

Comment: MessageMap.AddMessage<GraphEngine>(WM_LBUTTONDOWN, &GraphEngine::LeftMouseDown);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, вы используете библиотеку [ullib](https://ullib.googlecode.com/) для создания gui.

`MessageMap.AddMessage<GraphEngine>(WM_LBUTTONDOWN, &GraphEngine::LeftMouseDown);`

Вы регистрируете указатель на функцию одного класса (GraphEngine), а в последствии функция вызывается для другого класса (CULWnd). Создатели этой библиотеки вступили на скользкую дорожку кастинга указателей reinterpet_cast-ом.
Компилятор генерирует предупреждение,

```
warning C4407: cast between different pointer to member representations, compiler may generate incorrect code
```

Но видимо, это мало кого волнует. Смотрим далее, как происходит вызов этого коллбэка:

```
BOOL ProcessMessage(CULClass_t* pWnd,UINT uMsg , WPARAM wParam , LPARAM lParam)
{
    //...
            return(pWnd->*m_pMessageStorage[i].msMsgProc)(wParam,lParam);
    //...
};
```

Здесь pWnd  - указатель на базовый класс, а в msMsgProc хранится адрес функции наследника. Это уже само по себе плохо.

В некоторых случаях указатель на базовый класс и наследник совпадают, но не в вашем случае. Прежде чем можно будет обратиться к наследнику, надо сделать dynamic_cast:

```
dynamic_cast<GraphEngine*>(pWnd)
```

чтобы скорректировать указатель.

Потому что нельзя так просто обращаться к наследнику, имея указатель на базовый класс.

В итоге, при одиночном наследовании это худо-бедно работает, то при множественном наследовании происходит фейл. И при вызове функции `LeftMouseDown` указатель `this` вовсе не тот, который должен там быть, и вызов виртуальных функций ломается.

Вот простой пример для воспроизведения ошибки.
Может гуру C++ объяснят более подробно, что происходит с таблицами виртуальных функций в этом примере.

```
class Derived;

class Base {
public:
    void ProcessMessage() {
        (this->*callback_)(0, 0);
    }
    typedef LRESULT(Base::*MSGPROC)(WPARAM, LPARAM);
    MSGPROC callback_;
    virtual void dummyVirtualFunction(){} 
};

class IEngine {
public:
    virtual ~IEngine() {}
    virtual void Draw() {
        std::cout << "Draw" << std::endl;
    }
};
class Derived : public IEngine, public Base {

public:
    Derived() {
        callback_ = reinterpret_cast<MSGPROC>((CallBack)&Derived::LeftMouseDown);
    }
    void LeftMouseDown(WPARAM, LPARAM) {
        std::cout << this << " LeftMouseDown" << std::endl;
        Draw();
    }
    typedef void(Derived::*CallBack)(WPARAM, LPARAM);
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Base* o = new Derived();
    o->ProcessMessage();

    return 0;
}
```

Скорее всего, ваш код перестанет падать, если вы поменяете `public IEngine`  и `public ULWnds::CULWnd` местами. Но это ненадежное решение.

Comment: Не могу назвать себя гуру, но вызов метода одного класса по указателю на экземпляр другого класса — это жырнейшее UB. Это может случайно работать. Лэйаут таблиц виртуальных методов может поменяться от любого чиха оптимизатора и при любом, самом безобидном на вид изменении кода. Не говоря уже о том, что оптимизатор имеет право тупо заинлайнить что угодно с понятными последствиями. Так что на мой взгляд проблема в библиотеке, и вылет приложения — вопрос времени. В любом случае, +1.

Comment: @VladD очень многие библиотеки полагаются на конкретную реализацию компилятора при UB. Скажем, любят разыменовывывать нулевой указатель. Так что почти любая программа на C++ по стандарту не обязана работать.

Comment: Так и есть. И это ужасно.